# Test class for apex class which is selecting multiple record ids from list view

Tags: apex

Can anyone guide me how to write test class for below apex class.

Actually my class works when I select multiple records from list view and on clicking custom button, I am using VF Page to show the sum of amount of selected records.

Can anyone guide me on how to write test class as I don't have any idea how to start test class for selecting multiple records from list view.

```
public with sharing class PaymentSummaryController {


public boolean InError {get;set;}

public decimal TotalAmount {get;set;}
public decimal TotalAppliedAmount {get;set;}
public integer TotalItems {get;set;}

public List<EXECED_Payment__c> selectedIds {get;set;}

public PaymentSummaryController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
   selectedIds = (List<EXECED_Payment__c>) controller.getSelected();

    InError=false;
    controller.setPageSize(1000); 
    if (selectedIds==null || selectedIds.size()==0) {
        ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Please select at least one record.');
        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
        InError=true;
    } 
    else{
    String str = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('selectedIds');
        TotalAmount=0;
        TotalAppliedAmount=0;
        TotalItems=0;
        for (EXECED_Payment__c p : [select id,Amount__c,Total_Applied_Amount__c from EXECED_Payment__c where id in: selectedIds]){
            if (p.Amount__c!=null)
                TotalAmount+=p.Amount__c;
            if (p.Total_Applied_Amount__c!=null)
                TotalAppliedAmount+=p.Total_Applied_Amount__c;
            TotalItems++;
        }
    }
 }
 }
```

TestClass:

```
@isTest(SeeAllData = True)
private with sharing class PaymentSummaryControllerTest {
static testmethod void PaymentSummaryControllerTest(){
    EXECED_Payment__c pay = new EXECED_Payment__c(Payment_Owner__c='Account',Payment_Status__c='Credited',Amount__c=1000,Payment_Date__c=system.now(),Pay_Type__c='Check');
    EXECED_Payment__c pay1 = new EXECED_Payment__c(Payment_Owner__c='Account',Payment_Status__c='Credited',Amount__c=1000,Payment_Date__c=system.now(),Pay_Type__c='Check');
   List<EXECED_Payment__c> Exceeded = new List <EXECED_Payment__c>();
    Exceeded.add(pay);
    Exceeded.add(pay1);
    insert Exceeded;
   test.startTest();
    List<sObject> accts = (List<EXECED_Payment__c>)[Select Id From EXECED_Payment__c];
    System.debug(accts);
       Test.setCurrentPage(Page.PaymentSummary);
       ApexPages.StandardSetController controller = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(accts);
       controller.setSelected(accts);
       PaymentSummaryController ext = new PaymentSummaryController(controller);
    test.stopTest();

}

}
```

Comment: @david Reed, I tried the code for code coverage which I added to question but its not covering my code at all

Comment: I am able to do it on my own, I added my test class in the question itself by which I got code coverage.